# Guava - How to remove from a list, based on a predicate, keeping track of what was removed?

Tags: java, collections, filtering, guava, predicate

I have an `ArrayList` to be filtered, and various Guava `Predicate`s to filter it with. This list will have only 50-100 elements.

I was planning on `Iterables.removeIf` using each predicate in turn. It is perhaps not maximally efficient but never mind (at least `removeIf` has some optimization for RandomAccess lists)

For debugging, I want to concisely log what each predicate did. e.g.

```
Pred0 removed [a, c, g]
Pred1 removed []
Pred2 removed [b, f]
```

There are some obvious hack solutions but what would you suggest as the cleanest?

For bonus points, it should be reasonably efficient too. ;)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I would capture the removed elements in your Predicate code.

```
List<String> removedElements = Lists.newArrayList();
final Iterables.removeIf(list, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        if ("a".equals(input)) {
            removedElements.add(input);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up with too - I like its simplicity. I am sure it is not 100% kosher for a Predicate to have side effects, but I don't really care (we could make it idempotent etc. if we did care)

Answer (score 5):

This may be an occasion when using a loop is simplest.

```
List<MyType> list =
Predicate<MyType>[] predicates =
Map<Predicate, List<MyType>> removed = 
      new LinkedHashMap<Predicate, List<MyType>>();
for(Iterator<MyType> iter=list.iterator();list.hasNext();) {
   MyType mt = iter.next();
   for(Predicate<MyType> pred: predicates) 
       if(pred.apply(mt)) {
          List<MyType> mts = removed.get(pred);
          if(mts == null)
              removed.put(pred, mts = new ArrayList<MyType>());
          mts.add(mt);
          iter.remove();
          break;
       }
 }
```

Comment: A `Multimap<Predicate, MyType>` would make things more concise there too.

Comment: Thanks, I can see this works. ...It kinda makes me shudder to be `remove`'ing things from an `ArrayList.iterator()` but I suppose no worse in practice, for these small list sizes. (I was interested to see there is no custom strategy for `ArrayList.iterator().remove()` the way that Guava does in `Iterables.removeIf`).

Answer (score 4):

I'd investigate in *observable predicates*. The idea: everytime, a predicates `apply` method is about to return true, it will fire a notification to listeners:

```
Iterable<?> iterable = getIterable();
Collection<ObservablePredicate> predicates = getPredicates();
PredicatesLogger log = new PredicatesLogger(predicates);  // listens to all predicates
for (ObservablePredicate pred : predicates) {
  Iterables.removeIf(iterable, pred);
  log.print();
  log.reset();
}
```

The `ObservableLogger` is a decorator for `Predicate` :

```
public class ObservableLogger implements Predicate {
  private Predicate predicate;

  private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();
  // usual stuff for observer pattern

  @Override
  public boolean apply(Object input) {
    boolean result = predicate.apply(input);
    fire(result);
    return result;
  }

  // a fire method
}
```

The `PredicateLogger` needs one constructor that adds itself as a listener to the predicates. It will receive the notifications and cache the predicates that fired the events (the `Event` class needs an appropriate field for that information). `print` will create the log message, `reset` will clear the loggers cache (for the next run).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. For my single case it is probably too gold-plated. No point building reusable infrastructure when I may never need it again...

Comment: @Iain - what about some gold-plate for your skills :-D

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Peter's anwser.

But if you want to have fun, you could also wrap each of your predicate inside a predicate which would delegate to the wrapped predicate, and store the values for which true is returned inside a `Map<Predicate, List<Foo>> removedByPredicate` :

```
class PredicateWrapper implements Predicate<Foo> {
    private Predicate<Foo> delegate;

    public PredicateWrapper(Predicate<Foo> delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean apply(Foo foo) {
        boolean result = delegate.apply(foo);
        if (result) {
            List<Foo> objectsRemoved = removedByPredicate.get(delegate);
            if (objectsRemoved == null) {
                objectsRemoved = Lists.newArrayList();
                removedByPredicate.put(delegate, objectsRemoved);
            }
            objectsRemoved.add(foo);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yeah same idea as @JanRavn - thanks. (I like @PeterLawrey's concise two-liner way of managing a multimap; never thought of it...)

Answer (score -4):

I guess you need:

```
Predicate<XXX> predicate1 = new Predicate<XXX>(){  
    @Override  
    public boolean apply(XXX input) {  
        if(...) //satisfy your filter
            return true;  
        else  
            return false;  
}};  

Predicate<XXX> predicate2 = new Predicate<XXX>(){  
    @Override  
    public boolean apply(XXX input) {  
        if(...) //satisfy your filter
            return true;  
        else  
            return false;  
}};
Predicate allPredicates = Predicates.and(predicate1, predicate2);
//or Predicates.or(predicate1, predicate2);

Collection<XXX> list2 = Collections2.filter(list, allPredicates);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This funny `if (...) return true; else return false;` can be reduced to `...`.