# ArrayList filter

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

How can you filter out something from a Java ArrayList like if you have:

1. How are you
2. How you doing
3. Joe
4. Mike

And the filter is "How" it will remove Joe and Mike.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122105/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-filter-a-collection

Comment: best solution would be to use some other collection data structure instead of an arraylist: http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Probably the best way is to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("How are you");
list.add("How you doing");
list.add("Joe");
list.add("Mike");
    
Collection<String> filtered = Collections2.filter(list,
    Predicates.containsPattern("How"));
print(filtered);
```

prints

```
How are you
How you doing
```

In case you want to get the filtered collection as a list, you can use this (also from Guava):

```
List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(
    list, Predicates.containsPattern("How")));
```

Comment: What is the 2 in Collections2?

Comment: @DavoudTaghawi-Nejad That's probably because there is already `Collections` class in standard Java. So it's clear which class is which and you don't have to use fully qualified name to distinguish between them in case they are used in one class.

Comment: its giving error on Predicates as Predicate cannot be resolved in android..

Comment: got it.. i was using incorrect library.. now I am using guava-16.0.1.jar

Comment: How to filter string which does not "How"?

Comment: @taymedee use `not()`: `filter(list, not(Predicates.containsPattern("How"))`

Answer (score 79):

In [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8), they introduced the method [`removeIf`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) which takes a [`Predicate`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) as parameter.

So it will be easy as:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("How are you",
                                                  "How you doing",
                                                  "Joe",
                                                  "Mike"));
list.removeIf(s -> !s.contains("How"));
```

Comment: call requires API level 24

Answer (score 29):

Iterate through the list and check if contains your string "How" and if it does then remove. You can use following code:

```
// need to construct a new ArrayList otherwise remove operation will not be supported
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(new String[] 
                                  {"How are you?", "How you doing?","Joe", "Mike"}));
System.out.println("List Before: " + list);
for (Iterator<String> it=list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    if (!it.next().contains("How"))
        it.remove(); // NOTE: Iterator's remove method, not ArrayList's, is used.
}
System.out.println("List After: " + list);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
List Before: [How are you?, How you doing?, Joe, Mike]
List After: [How are you?, How you doing?]
```

Comment: What does it.next() return the first time it is called?

Comment: Calling `it.next()` first time returns very first item from the collection (list).

Comment: I like this one since it is the simplest one without involving third party libraries.

Answer (score 15):

write your self a filter function

```
 public<T> List<T> filter(Predicate<T> criteria, List<T> list) {
        return list.stream().filter(criteria).collect(Collectors.<T>toList());
 }
```

And then use

```
    list = new Test().filter(x -> x > 2, list);
```

This is the most neat version in Java, but needs JDK 1.8 to support lambda calculus

Answer (score 3):

I agree with a previous answer that [Google Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) is probably helping a lot here, readability-wise:

```
final Iterables.removeIf(list, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        if(input.contains("How")) { //or more complex pattern matching
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Please note that this is basically a duplicate of [Guava - How to remove from a list, based on a predicate, keeping track of what was removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494614/guava-how-to-remove-from-a-list-based-on-a-predicate-keeping-track-of-what-w)

Answer (score -9):

As you didn't give us very much information, I'm assuming the language you're writing the code in is C#.
First of all: Prefer System.Collections.Generic.List over an ArrayList.
Secondly: One way would be to loop through every item in the list and check whether it contains "How". Another way would be to use LINQ. Here's a quick example that filters out every item which doesn't contain "How":

```cs
var list = new List<string>();
list.AddRange(new string[] {
    "How are you?",
    "How you doing?",
    "Joe",
    "Mike", });

foreach (string str in list.Where(s => s.Contains("How")))
{
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: "As you didn't give us very much information", but there is your information, the post was tagged to Java.

Comment: @NeonWarge check edit history... http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9146224/revisions "Java" tag was added later after this answer.