# How to filter ArrayList by using multi member variable condition?

Tags: java

I'd like to get objects of DataObj which age greater than 32 and address is city2.

How to filter like this?

Following is tried code.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<DataObj> arr_datalist = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
        ArrayList<DataObj> arr_filteredlist;
        arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(1, "aka", 30, "city1"));
        arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(2, "akb", 31, "city2"));
        arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(3, "akc", 32, "city2"));
        arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(4, "akd", 33, "city1"));
        arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(5, "ake", 34, "city3"));

        // age greater than 32 and address is city2.
        arr_filteredlist = arr_datalist.filter(???);

    }
}

class DataObj {
    int i_id;
    String str_name;
    int i_age;
    String str_address;

    DataObj(int id, String name, int age, String address) {
        this.i_id = id;
        this.str_name = name;
        this.i_age = age;
        this.str_address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at this post, can be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146224/arraylist-filter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have several common options:

### Do it yourself:

```
List<DataObj> arr_filteredlist = new ArrayList<>();
for(DataObj e : arr_datalist) {
    if(e.i_age > 32 && e.str_address.equals("city2")) {
        arr_filteredlist.add(e);
    }
}
```

### Guava:

```
Collection<DataObj> filteredColl = Collections2.filter(arr_datalist,
    new Predicate<DataObj>() {
        @Override
        boolean apply(DataObj e) {
            return e.i_age > 32 && e.str_address.equals("city2");
        }
        // + overrides equals
    });
List<DataObj> arr_filteredlist = new ArrayList<>(filteredColl);
```

### Java 8:

```
List<DataObj> arr_filteredlist = 
    arr_datalist.stream()
                .filter(e-> e.i_age > 32 && e.str_address.equals("city2"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: solution of each version. :D 
Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Java 8, we will have lambdas. Your task can be solved by:

```
List<DataObj> filteredList = arr_datalist.stream()
                              .filter(dataObj -> dataObj.str_address.equals("city2") && dataObj.i_age > 32)
                              .map(DataObj::new)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @S.J.Lim Yes, can't wait for General Availability. You can download an early release too: https://jdk8.java.net/download.html

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<DataObj> filteredList = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
for (DataObj dataObj : arr_datalist) {
    if (32 < dataObj.getAge()  && "city2".equals(dataObj.getCity()) {
        filteredList.add();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no filter mechanism in java7 or previous versions. but you can easily do this yourself by checking each object:

```
    ArrayList<DataObj> arr_datalist = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    ArrayList<DataObj> arr_filteredlist = new ArrayList<DataObj>();
    arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(1, "aka", 30, "city1"));
    arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(2, "akb", 31, "city2"));
    arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(3, "akc", 32, "city2"));
    arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(4, "akd", 33, "city1"));
    arr_datalist.add(new DataObj(5, "ake", 34, "city3"));

    // age greater than 32 and address is city2.
    for(DataObj obj : datalist) {
        if(obj.getAge() > 32 && "city2".equals(obj.getAddress()) {
            filteredlist .add(obj);
        }
    }
```

I assmue your `DataObj` has private attributes and a getter for each attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Define a predicate**

```
Predicate<DataObj> filterPredicate = new Predicate<DataObj>() {
   public boolean apply(DataObj obj) {
    if(obj.getAge() > 32 && obj.getAddress.equals("city2") {
       return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Define your generic function**

```
public static <T> Collection<T> filter(Collection<T> source, Predicate<T> predicate) {
    Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T element: source) {
       if (predicate.apply(element)) {
          result.add(element);
      }
    }
   return result;
 }
```

**Call It**

```
 Collection<DataObj> filteredObjects = filter(arr_datalist, filterPredicate);
```

Comment: Note: you need Guava :)

Comment: @SilviuBurcea, no need to use guava in this case as you can create your Predicate class with apply method