# ArrayList filter based on some condition in android

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrayList` in android which contains several names. Suppose user typed R, so I want to calculate how many names are there in the `ArrayList` which starts with R. for example if arraylist contains Ashok, Bimal, Ram, Raju, sunita then it should return 2 as there are 2 names starts with R

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> _list;//ur arraylist with names
    for (String names : _list) {
        if (names.startsWith("R")) {
            count++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: thanx. now i want that if the user typed R then pnly those names will populate in the screen which starts with R.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate through the ArrayList and increment an integer variable when your check returns true.

Comment: While I upvoted this for exactly answering the question as it stands, I guess what @user3061048 actually meant was a full search functionality for the list.

Comment: Of course. But if he wants a more detailed answer he must spend a little more time on the question. I'm not doing the work for him. If he wants help with why his attempt does not work I will gladly take the time to debug it.

Comment: Yep, absolutely agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Ashok");
    list.add("Bimal");
    list.add("Ram");
    list.add("Raju");
    list.add("sunita");
    int count  = 0;
    for(String s: list){
        if(s.startsWith("R")){
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onCreate method

```
int countToShow=counterMethod(character);
TextView  showCount=(TextView)findViewById(idOfYourTextView);
showCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
```

Make another method in your activity as follow:-

```
public int counterMethod(String character){
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0; i<arrayListName.size();i++)
    {
        String name=arrayListName.get[i];
        if(name.startswith(character))
            count++;
    }
return count;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below code....

```
enter code here
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("How are you");
list.add("How you doing");
list.add("Joe");
list.add("Mike");

 Collection<String> filtered = Collections2.filter(list,
Predicates.containsPattern("How"));
 print(filtered);
```

Comment: Noting that this is not core Java but requires use of the guava library.

Comment: Copy cat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146224/arraylist-filter/9149673#9149673