# Whats an efficient way to filter an array based on a logical condition?

Tags: java, arrays, search, indexing, runtime

let say i have a 3x6 array of doubles:

*double[][] arr* =

```
            [1.2, 1,  1]
            [4.3, 1 , 1]
            [2.0, 1 , 1]
            [2.9, 1 , 1]
            [6.2, 1 , 1]
            [2.5, 1 , 1]
```

i want to return an array based on a tolerance of say x<3.0 for the ***first column only***.

Which will return the full array minus the rows that dont match the condition (x<3.0):

I.E.

*double[][] returnArr* =

```
               [1.2, 1,  1]                   
               [2.0, 1 , 1]
               [2.9, 1 , 1]                   
               [2.5, 1 , 1]
```

Whats an efficient way of accomplishing this (run time is a concern)???

Comment: You mean `double[][]`, right?  For both the input and the output?

Comment: You should consider using `ArrayList`.

Comment: I do mean 'double[][]', oops.

and could you maybe expand on how to best implement this with ArrayList (i'm very new to java)???

Comment: OK, first think about whether you need a deep copy of each matching `double[]` within the 2D array.

Comment: Do you need a filtered _copy_; or just a view?

Comment: I need a hard filtered copy :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your arrays are not sorted based on their [0] elements, 
the most efficient way is O(N) i.e. to loop through all the 
arrays (assuming their count is N) and test them for this condition.

Here is some sample code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test011 {

    private static double[][] arr = new double[][]{
        {1.2, 1,  1},
        {4.3, 1 , 1},
        {2.0, 1 , 1},
        {2.9, 1 , 1},
        {6.2, 1 , 1},
        {2.5, 1 , 1}
    };

    private static double[][] filter(double[][] d, double num){
        ArrayList<double[]> lst = new ArrayList<double[]>();

        for (int i=0; i<d.length; i++){
            if (d[i][0] < num){
                lst.add(d[i]);
            }
        }
        double[][] result = new double[lst.size()][];
        return lst.toArray(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] a = filter(arr, 3.0);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arr));
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(a));
    }

}
```

Comment: Are there any native methods that would accomplish this if the array was stored as an ArrayList?

Comment: Not that I know of. You're looking for lambda expressions I think. They will be there in JDK 8. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: Look here too. Maybe you can use Guava (which is still a thirdparty library). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146224/arraylist-filter

Comment: I can't imagine Guava having anything that would be any quicker than just iterating through the array and doing the right comparison.

Comment: OP, now I think you're not looking for an efficient way (in terms of time complexity) but just for a shorter way to do this with some Java code.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes, I just added a comment in the same direction. I think the OP is just looking for shorter code in terms of syntax than for better time complexity.

Comment: OP, if your data structure is not sorted, the time complexity will be O(N) regardless what library or syntax sugar you use.

Comment: I see, thank you.
My data is in fact NOT sorted... so i am hoping to get a hint for making some nice clean code for the filtering.