# How can i filter content in recycleview in main activity by pressing a button in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android, filter, android-recyclerview

I'm new to android. I was wondering if there was a way to press a button in a navigation drawer to filter contents in main activity. This is what i have so far. But it's not working.
**This is my button code from fragment activity**

```
Books.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent type = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
                type.putExtra("filterBooks_documents","filterBooks_documents()");
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(containerView);
                startActivity(type);


            }
            });
```

**This is my filter code in main activity onCreate() where my recyclerview is**

```
if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras == null) {

                //Extra bundle is null
            } else {
                String method = extras.getString("filterBooks_documents");

                if (method.equals("filterBooks_documents()")) {
                    mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), uploads);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                    mAdapter.getFilter().filter("Books_documents");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please, add actual code to your question, not screenshots of code.

Comment: don't post your code as images post as text

Comment: Sorry about that. See my update.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Filter Your List following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149673/8046011

Step 2: Update your adapter list by something like this:

```
mAdapter.updateList(filteredList);
```

Step 3: Tell your adapter the list has been changed.

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Hope this helps