# How get elements from an ArrayList based by multiple conditions?

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, arraylist

I'm creating an interface that manage the booking of Cinema tickets in different weeks/theatres.

I have a Film Class:

```
public class Film {

  private String title;
  private Double price;
  private String ageRestriction;
  private double rating;
  private String genre;
  private String location;
  private String screenDay;
}
```

A FilmList class that create and store all the Films in an ArrayList:

```
public class FilmList {

  private ArrayList <Film> filmArrayList;

  public FilmList (){
    this.filmArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addFilm(Film films){
    this.filmArrayList.add(films);
  }
```

And this is the graphic unit interface. What I'm trying to do is to catch in the ArrayList just *one element* based on two condition:
The Week and the Theatre selected from the user and also add a way for check that there's just one element on the list from the chosen parameters. This is important because each film instance will be called and "setted" on the Label of the FXML file (and because I'm thinking to implement an interface for add films in the ArrayList).

Thank's everyone.

Comment: OK, so if I understood you correctly you want to get a movie that satisfies two predicates from a movie list?

Comment: Yeah, exactly !

Comment: The way to get things from an `ArrayList` based on some conditions is to iterate over the list and look at each item to see if it meets your conditions.  If this sounds horribly inefficient, _it is_.  There are much better data structures to use if efficient searching is your goal.

Comment: Kevin thank'you for your comment. The efficiency it's not the first goal but I honestly asked for a less rough solution .

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146224/arraylist-filter) might help.

Comment: Imho something went wrong there in the OOA. It seems like the relation between Film and (location/screenDay) is a `1 - *` and the info should be seperated in a different object.

Comment: Research `FilteredList`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so in your example it would be something like following:

```
   //try to find any movie that suits two predicates, 1st - that it's price is greater than 30( this is random number, you can put a value from your textfield here ) and 2nd - that it's title contains Spiderman ( again, put a value from your textfield title search here for your need )
   Optional<Film> movie = listOfMovies.stream().filter(i -> i.getPrice() > 30 && i.getTitle.contains("Spiderman")).findAny();
  // if any movie has been found to suits provided criterias
   if(movie.isPresent())
       {
               //print it on screen, note method get()
               //again this is just for example here, in your code,
               // you can do with this result whatever you like
               // for example show all data about that movie on screen    
               System.out.println("---->" +movie.get());
       }
      else
       {
              // if not found do nothing
              System.out.println("Nothing found...");
       }
```

[More about Optional can be found here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

Comment: I'm using Java 1.8 but my course didn't covered yet the lambda expressions !

Comment: Are you allowed to use lambda expressions yet?

Comment: I'm. I can recognise it but I never used and I'm not so confident. But if you think that's the better way I'll try to understand better your chunk of code.

Comment: Take a look at provided example above now, @ArduinoMandarelli

Comment: Thank you so much ! Very helpful. 
Now the I'll try to implement it with the event handler, that probably will be the harder part 

Comment: No problem! If you get stuck with it, we can try it solving together here with SO community. One more note here: Bind your location to a Theater( might go for object creation here and put Theater instead of a String ) and your screenDay to Week( might go for Date object here as well ). ( I assume you have done it already. )

Comment: The code can  print both a movie and `Nothing found...`

Comment: Sorry, put it inside else {}... Code updated. Also for screenDay -> LocalDateTime would be prefered for this.