# return new instance of filtered elements

Tags: java

My Interface InterA:

```
public interface InterA
{
     boolean check(Record line);
}
```

My check-method:

```
public class ClassA implements InterA{

    @Override
    public boolean check(Record line) {
        if (condition) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can i return a new instance of ClassB in filter-method below only containing filtered elements?
Thank you in advance.

```
public class ClassB {

List<Record> list;

public ClassB(List<Record> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

public ClassB filter(InterA a) {


    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArrayList filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146224/arraylist-filter)

Comment: Inside filter method, iterate the list<Record> or like for(Record record: list) and then inside for loop, use a.check(record). If true, return new instance of ClassB.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Stream.filter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) to filter `Record`s matching the `criteria`. Then collect filtered elements into a list ([Stream.collect()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)), and create an instance of `ClassB` passing the list into the constructor.

```
public ClassB filter(InterA a) {
    return new ClassB(
        this.list
        .stream()
        .filter(a::check)
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
}
```

Comment: This suggestion needs some explaination about what it does and how it works.