# How To Filter An Array List By One Constructor Property?

Tags: java, filter, constructor

I have an array list, where all the entries look like this:

```
ListOfBooks.add(new Book("Holes", "Louis Sachar", 440419468, "Fiction", 1998, 5, 4));
```

But I only know how to filter out array lists containing strings. I'm using a constructor for entries:

```
public Book(String a, String b, int c, String d, int e, int f, int g) {
    this.title = a;
    this.author = b;
    this.isbn = c;
    this.genre = d;
    this.year = e;
    this.rating = f;
    this.copies = g;
}
```

My question is, how do I filter a list of books based only on it's title?

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: Take a look at the `filter` method in the Stream interface. Also, take a look at `Collectors.groupingBy`

Comment: I've tried stuff from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9146224/arraylist-filter) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's [Stream interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#package.description) and its [filter](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-filter-lambda) method allows us to filter `Book` objects based on its field `title` (or more generally, any `Object` based in its fields). Say you wanted to get all the books as a `List<String>` but only the books whose titles begin with "Baking Cookies". The following code will do just that:

```
List<Book> titles = ListOfBooks.stream()
    .filter(book -> book.title.startsWith("Baking Cookies"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is very useful, but is there a way to move all attributes (author, year, rating etc) to this list? Or is that what this does and I'm just dumb? Either way, thanks!

Comment: can you add an example to explain what you want.

Comment: @TongChen Ignore what I said, I'm just dumb. Ari gave just what I needed.

Comment: You may be new. Don't feel bad about yourself. Just try exploring the internet and try few things yourself. It will be faster and you will learn few more things.