# Remove specified object from List in Java when iterating

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to remove an object other than the current when iterating?

```
List<GameObjects> gameObjects = new ArrayList<GameObjects>();

ListIterator<GameObject> iterator = gameObjects.listIterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next().update();
    // Here I would like to do gameObjects.remove(other_object_in_gameObjects);
}
```

Obviously that's not allowed. But can an Iterator do it somehow? Or is it not doable at all?

Comment: Duplicate the list, remove from the copy, reassign it.

Comment: Where does other_object_in_gameObjects come from? Seems like you can just remove it outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what `other_object_in_gameObjects` is, but you can create a temp `List` recording the list items that needs to be deleted, and after the iteration remove all the items in the temp`List` that are also in `gameObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using the [Guava library](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#removeIf%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29). There is an `Iterables.removeIf` method that allows you to remove all objects from a list that match your criteria.

There's an example of usage at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494614/guava-how-to-remove-from-a-list-based-on-a-predicate-keeping-track-of-what-w).